# Multiple threads and multiple BufferedReaders

Tags: java, multithreading, java-io

I have a program which creates 4 Threads.
 In each thread I create a tcp connection.
Each connection has its BufferedOutputStream and BufferedReader.
Each TCP connection is handled by separated Thread
 The purpose of each thread is to process an array that I pass inside.
The problem is, that time spent on running each thread doesn't vary, according to amount of threads I create.
*After a long time sniffing, I found out that the problem is in reading from InputStream, precisely in line*
 `while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){do stuff}`
 When I comment this line of code, program run much faster, as it should be. 
I agree that thread gets blocked while reading from stream and it takes let's say 1 sec, but if I increase number of threads, job must be done faster. 
but in my case, in both 1 or 4 threads, I process same data, the same amount of time.
 What am I doing wrong ? Please help me out.

Comment: If each TCP connection has it's own reader, why do you suspect all threads are using the same reader?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are using blocking IO but don't expect it to block.

I suggest you either use;

- non-blocking IO (Not easy),
- use a thread for reading, or
- rethink your design with the expectation that readLine() should block.

Comment: Erm ... if the threads are blocked most of the time, then non-blocking I/O won't speed up the processing.  All it will do it allow you to do the same work with fewer thread.  If the number of threads is currently small (e.g. 4) then that isn't a win.

Comment: @StephenC if the "program run much faster" by commenting out the readLine() I suspect that waiting for the input in the thread he has is slowing it down. Reading in another thread would have a similar effect but be able to read as well.

Comment: Peter - I don't understand what you are saying.  Yes, waiting for the input is slowing the application down.  How ever, presumably the input is >>needed<< for the computation.  Hence, even if you used non-blocking I/O, there wouldn't be anything for the non-blocked thread to do while waiting for the data to arrive.

Comment: I guess if you could overlap the processing with the reading (your second suggestion) but that is only effective if a large enough proportion of time on each thread is used for processing the data.  The other imponderable here is whether the protocol is synchronous or asynchronous.  If it is synchronous then pipelining using a separate read thread probably won't be effective for speeding up the application

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInputStream does an I/O operation on every read and it synchronizes on all method calls to make it thread-safe. To reduce this overhead, read multiple bytes at once into a buffer array of bytes

    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream( name );
    enterbyte[] barray = new byte[SIZE];
    long checkSum = 0L;
    int nRead;
    while ( (nRead=f.read( barray, 0, SIZE )) != -1 )
    for ( int i=0; i<nRead; i++ )
        checkSum += barray[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your application is network-bound.  Basically, then network (or the server or client at the other end of the connection) cannot deliver data data enough to keep the threads busy.

It is unlikely that you can do anything *in this application* to significantly improve throughput.  You might get some traction by making the other end go faster ... or getting a faster end-to-end network connection.

---

> So it seems like, I have multiple threads, but all of them read from single BufferedReader, or something like that.

That contradicts what you said earlier.  If you have 4 threads that are reading and writing 4 separate sockets, then they will NOT be sharing a single `BufferedReader`.  The blocked threads are likely to be blocked while waiting to read on different readers.

Comment: Let's say I have 1000 lines of data. I put it in four arrays and those I pass into 4 threads where I do writing to PrintWriter and reading from BufferedReader . And to process these 1000 lines I spend 1 minute. If I do 2 threads with 2 arrays (same 1000 lines, divided by 500), I still spend 1 minute. BUT if I stop reading from BufferedReader, with 4 threads the job is done in 15 seconds.